# Analysis Services Deployment Wizard 2016

Tags: ssas, sql-server-2016, ssas-2016

In trying to run the Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Deployment.exe I get the following error

Could not load type 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ManagementDialogs.TabularProcessProgress' from assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ManagementDialogs, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'. (Analysis Services Deployment Wizard)

Any Ideads?

Answer (score 0):

Update the folder @ C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ManagementDialogs

to 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ManagementDialogs_Old

And the Wizard now works
[Rename Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfFI9.png)

Comment: I applied the 'hack' successfully to fix the wizard. Unfortunately I later got an issue when trying to open SSIS "Analysis Service Processing Task" components, giving the error:

**Cannot show the editor for this task.

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ManagementDialogs, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ASTasksUI)**

By reversing the directory rename and restarting VS the latter error was solved.

Comment: I do not consider this as the final answer, as is has unintended side-effects.